# How to find out what nuget packages are not used and should be removed from my project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, google-api, nuget

I have an MVC Application that works with Google API.

I find way to many Nuget packages installed.

**Is there a tool or another mechanism that can determine and help me to get rid of packages that are not being used by the application or by other packages?**

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951328/how-can-you-find-the-unused-nuget-packages-in-a-solution

Comment: try ResolveUR extension : https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fe96c042-9a83-4fa2-921d-6b09aa044315