# Visual Studio find nuget packages that aren't being used

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Sometimes I load Nuget packages into my solution that I don't end up actually using, or I use them for awhile, then switch to something else, and forget to remove the old package. I suspect that my solution has Nuget packages installed that I'm not actually using anymore.

Is there a way to find unused installed Nuget packages, other than removing them one by one and checking for build errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you find unused NuGet packages in solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951328/how-can-you-find-unused-nuget-packages-in-solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ReSharper](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/02/22/resharper-ultimate-10-1-eap-3/) to help you remove those unused NuGet packages.

> ReSharper 10.1 EAP significally improves performance on updating NuGet packages and analyzing project references. It also fixes a set of issues that used to break compilation by erroneously removing references that were in fact in use (which, for instance, used to happen when using the dynamic type).

**Note that**:ReSharper **does not** support for project.json projects ([RSRP-454515](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-454515)) and ASP.NET core projects ([RSRP-459076](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-459076))