# How can I reduce the size of rosyln folder in asp.net mvc project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, size, roslyn

I am developing an asp.net mvc 5 application with .net f/w 4.7 using C# which eventually will be deployed to azure.

Looking into the bin folder (both Debug and Release) after building my project I found a **roslyn** folder *15.7MB* in size.

Investigating further I found couple of *huge dll's* such as **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic , Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis**  to name a few.

Additionally there is **vbc.exe** (Visual Basic Compiler) which I am not using since I'm developing with C#

Following is a screen grab of my roslyn folder and nuget packages

[image: Rosyln Folder]

[image: Nuget Packages]

My question is

How can I reduce the size of the rosyln folder by identifying and removing unnecessary dll's specially *vb* related dll's.

Researching I found these [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc13a5a2-829b-4716-9830-e2efc24015ea/vs2015-file-size?forum=visualstudiogeneral), [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052851/avoid-significant-amounts-of-packages-and-binaries-when-using-roslyn-with-nuget),[so1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740123/what-why-is-roslyn-needed-in-bin-folder-of-asp-net) links which explain the some C# 6 features will be unavailable if I uninstall **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform** so is that a real viable solution going forward?

Help.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the size of that folder?

Comment: Remove unnecessary bloat.

Answer (score 1):

The folder is there to support dynamic compilation. So if you want that then it is not bloat and you should include it. If you want to remove it though you can follow these steps.

1. Remove "**Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform**" and "**Microsoft.Net.Compilers**" packages. (Some c# 6 feature will no longer work if you do not follow step 2)
2. In your publish profile settings, uncheck "Allow precompiled site to be updatable". You can find this under Settings > Precompile during publishing > configure. (This disables dynamic compilation and everything is precompiled.)