# Visual Studio not showing code suggestions for C# for one of the projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**Detail:**

I have updated Visual Studio to version 16.6.1 - couple days ago.

**1.**

I have noticed the code suggestion is not working anymore for one of my projects.

[image]

**2.**

But on my other project it does work..

[image]

**More detail:**

I have followed a suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8420870/12485722

Here is the current options:

[image]

**Question:**

How can I make it work again?...

Comment: What happens if you manually force VS to display IntelliSense? (By default `Ctrl+Space` should bring it up)

Comment: @MindSwipe Nothing sir. Tried these too.. nothing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640544/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-display-intellisense

Comment: Hello there. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18289936/10216583) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57474785/10216583) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27991492/10216583).

Comment: @JQSOFT tried it all. Even re-installing Visual Studio. It's just for specific project.. weird

Comment: Well, create a new project and add first the file that doesn't show the IntelliSense. If it works, add the rest to replace the old version.

Comment: @JQSOFT, please try to delete bin and obj folder in your project and restart your vs to check if it works for you.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT Nope - didn't work

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT Thank you buddy. I have no problem in this issue yet. LV98 has. Good suggestion Btw.

Comment: I believe the issue is coming from NuGet package - as I have been installing a number of packages without un-installing the ones I didn't need.

Comment: @LV98,It is may be related to your nuget, so after uninstalling unnecessary nuget, please try to delete bin and obj folder in your project and restart your vs to check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had multiple NuGet Packages that were not used at all.

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36645281/12485722

I have downloaded **ReSharper Ultimate 10.1 EAP 3** for **30 days trial** and **Remove Unused References** which also **supports NuGet references** as well.

Now the IntelliSense is up and running again.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried re-installing Visual Studio, it might solve your problem ?